# Get field names while running program

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I have a copy book like :

```
  01 MY-STRUCTURE.
     05 STRUCTURE-NAME PIC X(20).
     05 STRUCTURE-DATE PIC X(8).
     05 STRUCTURE-LIB PIC 9(3).
```

How can I get the name of my fields?

I want to have a program that can get any copybook and write dynamically its fields and values.

I want to write it to an output file like this :

```
  "STRUCTURE-NAME-> TOTO"
  "STRUCTURE-DATE-> 19780301"
  "STRUCTURE-LIB -> 123"
```

Comment: To clarify: you have a COBOL program "C", and you want "C" to be able to output any member or any structure that it contains? (The way you put the requirements, you might be asking for "C" to output the content of an arbitrary structure that it does NOT contain; where would it get such structure instances from?)

Comment: What compiler and OS are you using? What are you trying to actually achieve?

Comment: As Bill said, What are you trying to achieve ???. Basically you can write a parser for cobol-Copybooks, use an existing parser (e.g. file-aid on the mainframe or cb2xml) use the cobol-compiler to list record layout in a file.

Comment: Hi, I use Z/OS. I don't now for the compiler sorry.

Comment: I want to use only Cobol code to read my copybooks. I want write my copy book in a file like : "field1 : value-field1 \n field2 : value-field2 \n field3 : value-field3 \n ...

Comment: The \n is a Line break

Comment: This doesn't tell us what you want to do with that data. Do you have Filemanager or File-AID at your site? To do it yourself, reliably, would be a non-trivial amount of non-trivial code, and that is without a cross-reference of input data to copybook, or data to types.

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to Java's Reflection API?

Comment: HI, I like to display it. I want to "debug" my copybooks. Exactly like Java's Reflection API Yes.

Comment: COBOL doesn't have anything like Java's reflection API.

Comment: If your COBOL is "reading" copy-books, then it is in fact reading records from a file that contain simply field names and values as simple text. There's no problem displaying the field names and their VALUE clauses; just write substrings of the text to your output. The only 'values' the fields can have are coded as part of the copy-book itself. But if the copy-book is actually compiled as part of the program, the names are fixed (static, unchanging) and you know their names when the code is developed, no need to "read" them.

Answer (score 0):

In the z/OS world, depending upon your compiler level, you can use the debugging information generated by the compiler to do introspection on your names.  To do this, you will need to save your ADATA at compile time.

Answer (score -2):

I have a two possible solutions:

1. You save the names of the fields of the copy in a internal table. And secuential reads the table for your write your output.
2. Dynamical allocation, is more complicated but it's possible. You allocate the copy in your program using bpxwdyn (subroutine IBM).

   You create a subprogram, with name of copy, the length is fixed (80), the name of library of copys, and allocate this copy in subprogram. Then, You can fill a internal table with his datas.

Eg:

http://mainframe-tips-and-tricks.blogspot.com.es/2011/12/cobol-sample-program-for-dynamic-file.html

Comment: I want to sand any copybook in my sub-programm.

It can't work :(